# How to look up an amazon resource using the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) as an identifier?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

With respect to an Amazon Resource Name (ARN) the AWS documentation states that:

> Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) uniquely identify AWS resources. We require an ARN when you need to specify a resource unambiguously across all of AWS, such as in IAM policies, Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) tags, and API calls.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

**Question**

Is it possible to look up a specific AWS resource using the ARN as an identifier?

For example if I was to use the SDK would it be possible to do something along the lines of:

```
Instance instance = AmazonResourceName.find(arnId); // look up via ARN?
```

If this is not possible, then the question becomes:

***What is the recommended approach for finding an AWS resources using the API? and What are the identifiers available for look up? ***

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Do you specifically want EC2 instance or any type of object? It doesn't seem like the SDK has anything like a generic `AWSObject`. What would you do with this object?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [AmazonEc2Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html) docs?

It has a `describeInstances(DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest)` method that I think might suit your needs because the `DescribeInstancesRequest` can be set with ids as shown in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html#withInstanceIds-java.lang.String...-). This is untested but might be a good place to start.

Answer (score -2):

The following request returns the information associated with ItemId Meghshyam.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate ID]&  
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=MEGHSHYAM
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

The following request returns an offer for a refurbished item that is not sold by Amazon.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate ID]&  
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=MEGHSHYAM&
IdType=ASIN&
ResponseGroup=OfferFull&
Condition=All&
Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

In the following request, the `ItemId` is an SKU, which requires that you also specify the `IdType`.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate ID]&  
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=[SKU]&
IdType=SKU
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature
```

In the following request, the `ItemId` is a UPC, which requires that you also specify the `SearchIndex` and `ItemType`.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate ID]&  
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=[UPC]&
SearchIndex=Books&
&IdType=UPC
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

In the following request, the `ItemId` is an EAN, which requires that you also specify the `SearchIndex` and `ItemType`.

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate ID]&  
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=[EAN]&
SearchIndex=Electronics&
IdType=EAN
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```